# The simplest code not working (built in server)

Tags: php, php-7.2

php7.2

Could you help me understand why my code is not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Please, have a look at the attached image.
I run the built in server.

[image]

Comment: does the file have .php extension? Also I am so jealous, I wish I could get back that "Hello World" feeling :)

Comment: Dale, thank you. This was really the problem. If you organize an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a hunch I will take a guess that you are missing the file extension of `.php`